# Sum of multiple distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Three fish $F_1, F_2, F_3 $ are selected at random from the pond, their weights are independent and identically distributed $ \sim N(20.3, 0.13^2) $

a) Find $ P(\bar{F} \ge 20.1) $

b) Find $ P(F_1 + 2F_2  > 3F_3 + 0.1) $

Part a I think I get, I find $ \bar{F} \sim  N(20.3, \frac{0.13^2}{3})$
And then using a normal cdf I find it to be 0.996
Is this right?

Part b I really have no idea how to start

Comment: yes, thanks, my eye caught the wrong problem as I was typing it, and for some reason I just went with it. I need more tea with caffeine hah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $W=F_1+2F_2-3F_3-0.1$. Since the $F_i$ are independent,  $W$ has **normal** distribution, with mean $E(F_1)+2E(F_2)-3E(F_3)-0.1$ and variance $\text{Var}(F_1)+2^2\text{Var}(F_2)+3^2\text{Var}(F_3)$. We want the probability that $W\gt 0$.

**Remark:** There are several theorems involved here.

$1$.) Expectation is linear. For **any** random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, and any constants $a_1,\dots,a_n$, we have
$$E(a_1X_1+\cdots+a_nX_n)=a_1E(X_1)+\cdots +a_nE(X_n).$$

$2$.) If the $X_i$ are **independent**, then
$$\text{Var}(a_1X_1+\cdots+a_nX_n)=a_1^2\text{Var}(X_1)+\cdots +a_n^2\text{Var}(X_n).$$

$3$.) If the $X_i$ have normal distribution, and are independent, then 
$a_1X_1+\cdots +a_nX_n$ has normal distribution.

Comment: you're the hero this city needs, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.